# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, exception, null, nullpointerexception

I'm getting the following error:

```
Input date: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Project03.GetMonthInfo(Project03Driver.java:89)
    at Project03.appMain(Project03Driver.java:63)
    at Project03Driver.main(Project03Driver.java:18)
```

I think it may be referring to my use of `Integer.parseInt(stdin.readLine());`

Not completely sure.  This is my first time ever writing java.  Here's my code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Project03Driver
{
    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException
    {
        Project03 app;
        app = new Project03();
        app.appMain();
    }
}  // end class Project03Driver 

class Project03 
{

    // Instance (global) data declarations
   /* Output iCode, uSold, uCost, uPrice
   Output extCost, extPrice, iProfit */
   /* Output totExtCost, totExtPrice, totProfit, totTax
   Output avgProfit, lowUsold, lowUsoldIcode */

    float iCode;
    float uSold;
   float uCost;
   float uPrice;
   float extCost;
   float extPrice;
   float iProfit;

   float totExtCost;
   float totExtPrice;
   float totProfit;
   float totTax;
   float avgProfit;
   float lowUsold;
   float lowUsoldIcode;

   // additional variables needed for compile

   float totUsold;
   int date;
   int taxRate;
   int profitRate;


    BufferedReader stdin;

void appMain() throws IOException
{ 
  //Output assignment
  System.out.println("Assignment: Project #3" + "Written by:  Evan Tanguma");

  InitReport();
  GetMonthInfo();
  DisplayMonthInfo();


  while (iCode != 0)
  {
      ProcItem();
  }

  DisplaySummary();

}

void InitReport() throws IOException
{
   totUsold = 0;
   totExtCost = 0;
   totExtPrice = 0;
   lowUsold = 100;
   iCode= -11;  //need to set to a value which is not the flag
}

void GetMonthInfo() throws IOException
{
   //Input date, taxRate, profitRate
   System.out.print("Input date: ");
    date = Integer.parseInt(stdin.readLine());

   System.out.print("Input taxRate: ");
    taxRate = Integer.parseInt(stdin.readLine());

   System.out.print("Input profitRate: ");
   profitRate = Integer.parseInt(stdin.readLine());
}

void DisplayMonthInfo()
{
   //Output date, taxRate, profitRate
   System.out.println("The value of date is: " + date);
    System.out.println("The value of taxRate is: " + taxRate);
   System.out.println("The value of profitRate is: " + profitRate);
}

void ProcItem() throws IOException
{
   GetIcode();
   if (iCode != 0)
   {
      GetItemDetails();
      CalculateDetailTotals();
      UpdateLows();
      DisplayItemDetails();
   }
}

void GetIcode() throws IOException
{
   // user input iCode
   System.out.print("Input iCode: ");
    iCode = Integer.parseInt(stdin.readLine());
}

void GetItemDetails() throws IOException
{
   // user input uSold, uCost
   System.out.print("Input uSold: ");
    uSold = Integer.parseInt(stdin.readLine());

   System.out.print("Input uCost: ");
    uCost = Integer.parseInt(stdin.readLine());
}

void CalculateDetailTotals()
{
   uPrice = uCost * (1 + profitRate);
   extCost = uSold * uCost;
   extPrice = uSold * uPrice;
   iProfit = extPrice - extCost;

   totUsold = totUsold + uSold;
   totExtCost = totExtCost + extCost;
   totExtPrice = totExtPrice + extPrice;
}

void UpdateLows()
{
   if(uSold < lowUsold)
   {
      lowUsold = uSold;
      lowUsoldIcode = iCode;
   }
}

void DisplayItemDetails()
{
   /* Output iCode, uSold, uCost, uPrice
   Output extCost, extPrice, iProfit */

   System.out.println("iCode is: " + iCode);
   System.out.println("uSold is: " + uSold);
   System.out.println("uCost is: " + uCost);
   System.out.println("uPrice is: " + uPrice);
   System.out.println("extCost is: " + extCost);
   System.out.println("extPrice is: " + extPrice);
   System.out.println("iProfit is: " + iProfit);



}

void DisplaySummary()
{
   /* Output totExtCost, totExtPrice, totProfit, totTax
   Output avgProfit, lowUsold, lowUsoldIcode */

   System.out.println("totExtCost is: " + totExtCost);
   System.out.println("totExtPrice is: " + totExtPrice);
   System.out.println("totProfit is: " + totProfit);
   System.out.println("totTax is: " + totTax);
   System.out.println("avgProfit is: " + avgProfit);
   System.out.println("lowUsold is: " + lowUsold);
   System.out.println("lowUsoldIcode is: " + lowUsoldIcode);

}

} // end of class
```

Comment: Don't confuse `java` and `javascript`.

Comment: You never initialize your `stdin` variable.

Comment: "I think it may be referring" - in cases like these, it's best to fire up a debugger and actually check what's `null` when it shouldn't be.

Comment: You seriously need to clean up your code. As it stands, your code is a mess, and is barely underatsndable. Things you can do: Combine related data items into a specialized 'data storage' class, get rid of the extra blank lines, put your open braces on the same line as the method header, get rid of any junk comments you have, and add complete javadoc comments to all the methods.

Comment: Also, please, replace the three lines in your `Project03Driver` class main method with just `new Project03().appMain()`. Better yet, get rid of the 'driver' class, and put the main method straight in the `Project03` class.

Comment: First use your editor to tell you where line #89 is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Input date: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Project03.GetMonthInfo(Project03Driver.java:89)
```

From the stack trace: you haven't initialized `stdin` instance of `BufferedReader` of `Project03` class. Your invocation of `app.appMain();` inside the `main(args)` function is calling `GetMonthInfo();`,inside of which you are trying to execute `Integer.parseInt(stdin.readLine())`: as `stdin` is `null`, you can't invoke `readLine()` on this. Initialize it as follows in the `Project03` class context:

```
BufferedReader stdin =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

Comment: I really appreciate it.  Seems like a simple mistake now, but I was really hung up over that.  Just had to change a few other things around with my floats and it runs as needed now.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The stacktrace is a good indicator of where the problem exists — the variable `stdin` has yet to be initialized:

```
stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```